# GLMM using glmer() -- lack of convergence with a TEXTBOOK EXAMPLE

Tags: lme4-nlme, convergence, glmm

A supposedly simple, textbook example of a binary GLMM using adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature with 5 fixed and 1 random effect is not converging. The example analysis that I'm trying to reproduce is from Hosmer et al (2013: 347).

The following code reproduces the problem:

```
install.packages("aplore3")
require(aplore3)
data("polypharm")
polypharm$ID <- factor(polypharm$id) #Turn the Random Effect into a factor
polypharm$inptmhv2 <- as.numeric(polypharm$inptmhv3 != "0")
polypharm$race2 <- as.numeric(polypharm$race != "White")
polypharm$gender_m <- as.numeric(polypharm$gender == "Male")
require(lme4)
mixed1 <-     
  glmer(polypharmacy ~ gender_m + age + mhv4 + race2 + inptmhv2 + (1|ID),
      nAGQ = 2, # AFAIK this needs to be set to >1 or it's not GHQ
        family = binomial, 
          data = polypharm)
```

And the result is

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.339924 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

In the help file, the author of glmer() says that up to 25 quadrature points may be used when there's only one random effect. I therefore tried refitting the model with every nAGP value from 1 through 25 (not shown), but none of those models converges either.

The model does converge when nAGP is set to 0 but, as I understand it, that method is essentially a cheap shortcut that sacrifices estimation accuracy -- and sure enough, the estimates thus obtained are quite different from those in Hosmer et al's example.

Since this dataset was specifically selected by eminent statisticians to serve as a didactic example of GLMMs, it seems hard to believe that convergence should be so hard to attain. The most plausible explanation is that I'm messing something up. But what?

I'm not opposed to using other packages either. But the chart on page 131 of [this article](http://avesbiodiv.mncn.csic.es/estadistica/curso2011/regm26.pdf) straightforwardly suggests that GHQ is the way to go, and glmer() seems the default choice for that.

References:

Hosmer, D. W., Lemeshow, S. & Sturdivant, R. X. (2013). *Applied logistic regression* (3rd ed.). Hoboken, N.J.: Wiley.

Comment: No reason to panic. Just optimise harder. `mixed1 <- glmer(polypharmacy ~ gender_m + age + mhv4 + race2 + inptmhv2 + (1|ID), nAGQ = 10, family = binomial,  data = polypharm, control = glmerControl( optimizer ='optimx', optCtrl=list(method='nlminb')))` works fine.

Comment: Many thanks. That solves it. I now see that some of the many other threads about GLMM nonconvergence refer to this kind of fix. But it's uncertain whether someone unfamiliar with the technicalities of GLMM fitting (such as myself) could have comprehended and applied that information without you kindly supplying the exact lines of code.

Comment: No problem! We are always happy to help. Welcome to the CV community! You already did half the steps required yourself when you recognised that you need to change the number of points per axis for evaluating the adaptive Gauss-Hermite approximation. it was the just the final stride that was missing.